# In the below code,Instead i want an alternate method to fetch the data from controller if it is success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

In the below code, I don't want to check as data.msg. like that--Instead I want an alternate method to fetch the data from controller if it is success (without using strings or boolean values like SuccessWithPass).

### Controller code:

```
if (item.QualityReconciliation == StatusCodeConstants.QTYRECONCILIATIONFAIL) {
    status = true;
    statusMsg = "SuccessWithFail";                        
    break;
} else {
    status = true;
    statusMsg = "SuccessWithPass";
}
}

return Json(new { status = status, statusMsg = statusMsg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

### Script code:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    if (data.msg == "SuccessWithFail") {
        ModalAlertConfirm("Quality reconcilition is failed. do you want to continue?", "/accountpayable/accountpayable/SupplierInvoiceDetail?OrderId=" + OrderId);
    }
    if (data.msg == "SuccessWithPass") {
        location.href = "/accountpayable/accountpayable/SupplierInvoiceDetail?OrderId=" + OrderId;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
if (item.QualityReconciliation == StatusCodeConstants.QTYRECONCILIATIONFAIL) {
    success = false;
} else {
    success = true;
}

return Json(new { success = success}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        location.href = "/accountpayable/accountpayable/SupplierInvoiceDetail?OrderId=" + OrderId;
    } else{
        ModalAlertConfirm("Quality reconcilition is failed. do you want to continue?", "/accountpayable/accountpayable/SupplierInvoiceDetail?OrderId=" + OrderId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item.QualityReconciliation == StatusCodeConstants.QTYRECONCILIATIONFAIL) 
{
        return Json(Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else 
{        
        return Json(errorInformation, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

$.get(url, function (data) {
     if (data.errorInformation == 'undefined') {
        location.href = "/accountpayable/accountpayable/SupplierInvoiceDetail?OrderId=" +   OrderId;
     }
    else{
       alert("OOPS!! Error occured.")
    }
});
```